Brother network printer not working with IPP protocol?
Can it be that ipp printers don't work with Ubuntu?
Scenario: Old printer broke and replaced by a new one (both Brother; only slightly different model). Printer is recognized by the PC running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Query of lpstat reveals the printer is "deactivated". cups-browsed is up and running. Printer successfully pinged.
What's wrong here... any help appreciated. -mgw
